# vim logfile reviewer auto file follower

Tags: quickfix, plugin

I am sure this has been solved, but I cannot find a matching question.

I have a log file with the format:

`<LOG SEVERITY> <FILENAME> (<LINENO>) @<TIME> <MESSAGE>`

Where `<FILENAME> and <LINENO>` are the file and line in the src code that printed that message to the logfile.

I want have a split vim window with the logfile in one window, and the file that line in the log points to in the other window.

I have looked at:

- vim-logreview
- quickfix
- `<c-w>f`

`<c-w>f` is the closest to what I want.  But I want it to auto update when I move the cursor in the logfile.  I also want it to move to the line pointed to by the logfile.

I have tried the quickfix feature using :grep for specific patterns, but this only lets me navigate through the logfile.  I want to navigate through the files pointed to by the logfile entries.

Answer (score 1):

> `<c-w>f` is the closest to what I want.

There's also <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> that accepts line number and it's documented right next to <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>.

> But I want it to auto update when I move the cursor in the logfile.

Of course, you can trap `<CursorMoved>` and do some stuff automatically, but IMO it always creates more problems than it solves. It is much more natural to remap, say, `<CR>` to open preview on demand, e.g.

```
nnoremap <buffer>CR :pedit +<C-R>=matchstr(getline('.'), '(\zs\d\+\ze)')<CR> <cfile><CR>
```

Then put it under your custom "ftplugin" and you're done.